# Unknown column in on clause Java Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to execute an HQL for a many to many mapping in hibernate and getting a weird issue:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown columnallowedage1_.allowedAgencies_organization_id' in 'on clause'
>
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
>
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)

Basically, I have two tables, Reservation_Reason_Type and Agency. I need to do a many to many before them. I believe I'm doing everything correctly, but when I run the code, its giving me this unknown column issue. Not sure why it is doing allowedage1_allowedAgencies_organization_id. It is including the variable name in generated HQL as well.

Below are the mapped classes:

Agency.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AGENCY")
public class Agency {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="organization_id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="acronym")
    private String acronym;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "allowedAgencies")
    private Collection<ReservationReasonType> allowedReservations = new ArrayList<ReservationReasonType>();
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAcronym() {
        return acronym;
    }

    public void setAcronym(String acronym) {
        this.acronym = acronym;
    }

    public Collection<ReservationReasonType> getAllowedReservations() {
        return allowedReservations;
    }

    public void setAllowedReservations(Collection<ReservationReasonType> allowedReservations) {
        this.allowedReservations = allowedReservations;
    }

}
```

ReservationReasonType.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESERVATION_REASON_TYPE")
public class ReservationReasonType {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "reservation_reason_type_id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @Column(name = "reservation_reason_type_code")
    private String code;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="RES_AGENCY", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="reservation_reason_type_id")}
                                        , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="organization_id")})

    private Collection<Agency> allowedAgencies = new ArrayList<Agency>();
    
    
    public ReservationReasonType(int id, String description, String code) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setDescription(description);
        this.setCode(code);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Collection<Agency> getAllowedAgencies() {
        return allowedAgencies;
    }

    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="RES_AGENCY", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="reservation_reason_type_id")}
                                        , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="organization_id")})
    //Set<Agency> allowedAgencies = new HashSet<Agency>();
    public void setAllowedAgencies(Collection<Agency> allowedAgencies) {
        this.allowedAgencies = allowedAgencies;
    }
}
```

Below is the query that I'm using for HQL:

```
String query = "select rrt from ReservationReasonType as rrt join rrt.allowedAgencies age where age.acronym = :agencyAcronym)";
```

Below is the generated HQL which won't run because of the unknown columns:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        reservatio0_.reservation_reason_type_id as reservat1_2_,
        reservatio0_.reservation_reason_type_code as reservat2_2_,
        reservatio0_.description as descript3_2_ 
    from
        RESERVATION_REASON_TYPE reservatio0_ 
    inner join
        RES_AGENCY allowedage1_ 
            on reservatio0_.reservation_reason_type_id=allowedage1_.allowedReservations_reservation_reason_type_id 
    inner join
        AGENCY agency2_ 
            on allowedage1_.allowedAgencies_organization_id=agency2_.organization_id 
    where
        agency2_.acronym=?
```

I double checked whether I'm  doing the mapping right, and I think there isn't any issue with that. One thing I'm not sure of is that I'm using Hibernate 3.0, hibernate jpa 2.0, and mysql 8.0.19. Not sure if it can be an issue with that?

Need help.

**UPDATE:**

For a temporary solution, I added the below two columns to the RES_AGENCY table and its working, but this is just a bandaid. Still trying to figure out what can be a proper solution:

allowedReservations_reservation_reason_type_id
allowedAgencies_organization_id

Comment: have a look at this, please, https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/